# VB If statement for Varible after removing amount its not enough when i get it back up

Tags: vb.net, if-statement

Im making a cookie clicker type game and it wont let me Do an if statement more then once? its just returning false even when true

```
Private Sub btnUpgrade_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUpgrade.Click
    If cake = 10 Then
        upgrade1 = upgrade1 + 1
        cake = cake - 10
        lblUpgrade.Text = "Upgraded"
    Else
        lblUpgrade.Text = "Not Enough Cakes"
    End If
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: What do you mean by "do an if statement more than once"?  There's nothing inherently wrong with this code.  If `cake` doesn't equal `10` then the `If` condition is `False`.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: So if i have 10 and i spend them by clicking the button then it sets it to 0 and then i earn the 10 again it will say i dont have enough when i do

Comment: I would change the if to "If cake >= 10 Then", because what if you happen to have 11? Your statement wouldn't allow you to upgrade even though you have the required number of "cake" to do so...

Comment: @HarryJeacock: Then clearly you need to do some debugging here.  We don't know what other code you have or what else is modifying that `cake` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't understand your question but why don't you use :

```
If cake >= 10 Then
```

instead of

```
If cake = 10 Then
```

Good luck! Hope I helped you!